# how to concat an image from drawables?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, concatenation, android-drawable

How do I `concat image` from `drawables`?
I tried, but the output is the `id` of the face.
Is there any other way to do it?

```
fun talk(username: String?, message: String): String {
    val receive = message.toLowerCase()
    when {
        receive.contains("hello") -> {
            var user = ""
            if (username != null) {
                user = " " + username
            }
            return "Hello$user!"
        }
        receive.contains("hey") -> return "Hey $username!"
        receive.contains("ow") -> return "omg"
        receive.startsWith("do ") -> return "Yes, I do."
        receive.contains("time") -> return "It's " + TimeUtils.calendarToString(Calendar.getInstance(), null) + "."
        receive.contains("today") -> return "It's " + TimeUtils.calendarToString(Calendar.getInstance(), "M/d(E)")
        else -> {
            var reply = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
            if (receive.length > 7) {
                reply += ", consectetur adipiscing elit, " + "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. "
            }
            return reply
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you using `drawable`?

Comment: in  receive.contains("ow") -> return "omg" + R.drawable.face_1

Comment: I'm sorry but to me your example is quite not clear.. Could you please provide some real code?

Answer (score 0):

You can't concat Drawable and String. You could use `TextView` and `ImageView` which you could add to some `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout`.

My guess is you are trying to use emojis and if you want to show emojis you should use String with emojis in [EmojiTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/text/emoji/widget/EmojiTextView.html). If you want some emoji you should use unicode code for that emoji, for example `"omg \u1F60E"`

P.S. `R.drawable.face_1` and similar aren't Drawable but drawable ids and are actually of type Int.